# Error in t.default(replicate(length(p), p))

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following array:

```
> p
     [,1]
[1,]  0.2
[2,]  0.4
[3,]  0.0
[4,]  0.0
[5,]  0.4
[6,]  0.0
```

where

```
> typeof(p)
[1] "double"
```

and

```
> str(p)
 num [1:6, 1] 0.2 0.4 0 0 0.4 0
```

When I go to execute the code

```
t(replicate(length(p), p))
```

I obtain the error:

```
 Error in t.default(replicate(length(p), p)): argument is not a matrix
```

Why?

Comment: You are replicating a matrix and the output is an `array` or 3 dimensions.  Instead try `t(replicate(length(p), p[,1]))`  Also check the output of `replicate(length(p), p)`

Comment: To add on to the comment from @akrun, `t` only accepts matrices or data.frames as arguments. See the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html)

Comment: I followed your suggestions and now the program runs successfully. Thank you!